# Problems with jQ image selector

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I had a similar problem here:
[jQuery function for specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463971/jquery-function-for-specific-class)
which I solved. But it bugged me because it has too many divs and it does not look very nice, so I rewrote my HTML code and rewrote the selector script. 
Now the script loads images fine (it fades them all in) but selection does not work at all.
I tried using closest and siblings functions, but to no avail.

How can I solve this?
You can find the page in question at:
http://baldino.rs/baby-program/

Thanx in advance

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var picture = $('.post-cipela').each(function(index, element) {
$(this).find('.cipela-bg img:eq(0)').fadeIn(500);

$('.colorwrap a').click(function(){
  var index = $(this).find(".colorwrap a").index(this);
    $('.cipela-bg img').fadeOut(200);
    $('.cipela-bg img:eq('+index+')').fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

EDIT-1:
I revised my script. Now I have a problem because my image fades in multiple times. How can I fix it? - Here is the revised script, and the page where you can see the problem is here:
http://baldino.rs/baby-program

```
$(document).ready
(
function()
{
$(".cipela-1").fadeIn(200);
$(".colorwrap a").click
(
    function()
    {
        var item = $(this);
        var a = item.attr("rel");
        item.closest(".post-cipela").find(".cipela-1, .cipela-2, .cipela-3, .cipela-
        4").fadeOut(200);
        item.closest(".post-cipela").find("."+a).first().fadeIn(200);

    }
);
} 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

your code that you pasted is maligned, you have an extra `});` at the end.

In addition, you are wrapping the $('.colorwrap a') selector within your `.each` function loop, I'm not sure if you meant that.

Further, you have missed a bit on scoping your this variable.

this line within your `each` is fine.

```
$(this).find('.cipela-bg img:eq(0)').fadeIn(500);
```

but then you instantiate a click handler

```
$('.colorwrap a').click(function(){
  var index = $(this).find(".colorwrap a").index(this);
```

the $(this) within that handler refers to the matched `a` within `.colorwrap`.  You are then finding another instance of `.colorwrap a` underneath that, which probably doesnt exist, hence your selector not finding anything.

If you do indeed intend on wrapping this click handler on each .each iteration, you should assign `$(this)` to a variable within your loop, and use it within the click handler like this

```
var picture = $('.post-cipela').each(function(index, element) {
    var that =$(this);
    that.find('.cipela-bg img:eq(0)').fadeIn(500);

    $('.colorwrap a').click(function(){
        var index = that.find(".colorwrap a").index(this);
        $('.cipela-bg img').fadeOut(200);
        $('.cipela-bg img:eq('+index+')').fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, I totally started writing the script on the wrong foot, read my post edit.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanx for pointing me in the right directon. Away from each() that is.